# Rally custom report visibility

Tags: rally

I have created a custom report and it shows up on my "Reports" tab. How can I make this public to everyone in the project so that they can see it in their workspace?

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are referring to a Rally built-in custom report or have you written your own custom coded app that you would like to share?

Comment: I would like to share my own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to share the app with other users you need workspace or subscription admin privileges.

https://prod.help.rallydev.com/create-custom-pages#share

Comment: I'll tell my admin to try this. Thanks!

Comment: Admin has an option to "share with all users". Thanks. I was wondering if there is a way to share only with particular users or a particular project. I guess not.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to share it with only a subset of users.  What we often do for custom apps that are only useful for a small subset of users is have the admin share it, then have the subset of users copy it and then have the admin un-share it.  Note, we resort to this solution to save the limited number of shared dashboards we have to apps and reports that are relevant to all teams. The problem with this solution is it makes it challenging to upgrade the app with new features.  Nonetheless, I thought I would mention as an option if you are limited to the number of shared dashboards.

Comment: I guess we can try out this option. Thanks!